# AndroidX StringDef values inside interface

Tags: java, android, androidx

I am currently replacing some enums with androidx's StringDef, looking at the docs I noticed they use it like so :

```
  @Retention(SOURCE)
  @StringDef({
     POWER_SERVICE,
     WINDOW_SERVICE,
     LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE
  })
  public @interface ServiceName {}
  public static final String POWER_SERVICE = "power";
  public static final String WINDOW_SERVICE = "window";
  public static final String LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE = "layout_inflater";
```

In my current situation I would like to declare multiple StringDefs in the parent class. For the sake of structure and code cleanness would there be any downsides in declaring the values in the @interface instead of outside like so :

```
    @Retention(SOURCE)
    @StringDef({
            ServiceName.POWER_SERVICE,
            ServiceName.WINDOW_SERVICE,
            ServiceName.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE
    })
    public @interface ServiceName {
        String POWER_SERVICE = "power";
        String WINDOW_SERVICE = "window";
        String LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE = "layout_inflater";
    }
```

Are there any downsides of doing so ? Would this be frowned upon by other Android developers or is it just a matter of preference ?

Comment: The whole concept of StringDef/IntDef is generally frowned upon in my experience. IntDef can always be justifiable since ints are primitives, they use a few bytes less... yet that still amount to premature optimization to me. But strings result in the exact same memory usage as enums, so why would you want that, especially since you already got enums?

Comment: I totally agree actually, I am not a big fan of StringDef either, I need to pass on params to a specific function and to avoid other devs passing on unsupported values I was using enums. The value is normally a String, so when declaring the enum values I was overriding their toString function. This was working fine when going from enum to string but when going from String to enum I use a custom mapper function. But doing this feels like reinventing the wheel in my opinion. StringDef does the same without needing enum-string mapping and while restricting the values that can be passed on